# Reveal.js slide(s) inside bootstrap grid layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, reveal.js

Is it possible to integrate a reveal.js presentation (or a single slide) into a bootstrap grid layout (using a single page, no iframes), so that the reveal-part of the page is only taking for example half of the webpages size?

I would like to do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>normal page content (not part of the reveal.js presentation)</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn-primary">bootstrap button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section>
                    <h1>My Slide</h1>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I get is a page where the slide is not displayed and the bootstrap styling is broken. Somehow I would need to isolate both css style sheets.

It also seems that reveal.js slides always fill the browser window / page completely (and get zoomed/scaled only to fit the page size when the browser-window gets resized for example)

What I tried so far:

- Setting the width and height of the reveal presentation (this had no effect)
- Putting the reveal.js part of the page into an iframe. This works but then I can not load data via angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the CSS output it seems that reveal.js gives the slides a fixed depending on your window size. For example: `width: 960px; height: 700px; zoom: 1.26309;`

Bootstrap also tries to set a fixed width on content via the container div. For the example screen size above it uses: 
`@media (min-width: 1200px) .container {width: 1170px;}`

[image]

So it is trying to put a 1170px container in a 960px slide (zoomed to fill screen), which is going to cause issues. Removing the container div fixes this issue in this simple example:

[image]